# Why does get_template_directory_uri() not include "www", only for enqueued stylesheets?

Tags: functions, redirect, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

My site's url is set up to include www in `settings -> general`.
I also put it at the very top of my `functions.php`:

```
update_option('siteurl','http://www.federal-lawyer.com');
update_option('home','http://www.federal-lawyer.com');
```

However, when I use the `get_template_directory_uri();` function it outputs the non-www URL when enqueuing stylesheets. Any ideas on why this may be happening?

for example, in functions.php

```
wp_register_style('main-css',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('main-css');
```

outputs

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='main-css-css'  href='http://federal-lawyer.com/material/themes/fedlaw/css/main.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Interestingly, this doesn't happen for scripts enqueued in the functions.php file.

```
$java_script_url = get_template_directory_uri().'/js/';
wp_register_script('flex_slider', $java_script_url.'flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array('jquery'), '2.2.0', true);
wp_enqueue_script('flex_slider');
```

Comment: do you have any plugins or theme code which may be filtering `style_loader_src` or `style_loader_tag`?

Comment: It cannot output one thing in one place and another thing in another place without something else changing between the two. So if it's doing something different for scripts vs. styles, then you have code elsewhere that is altering it in between those two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the siteurl and home should be done in wp-config.php.

1. Remove them from functions.php.
2. Add the below into wp-config.php (making sure they don't already exist).

   `define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://www.federal-lawyer.com' );`

   `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.federal-lawyer.com' );`

Comment: The OP is using `update_option` in `functions.php` not `define`, but yes, the values should be `define`d in `wp-config.php` or set in the backend, not updated halfway through the WordPress boot.